# Cloudflare pages worker error when running wrangler dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudflare-workers, faunadb, cloudflare-pages

I'm following [this tutorial](https://fauna.com/blog/getting-started-with-fauna-and-cloudflare-workers) (to get cloudflare pages working with fauna db), but when I get to the chapter ["Testing and deploying the Worker"](https://fauna.com/blog/getting-started-with-fauna-and-cloudflare-workers#testing-and-deploying-the-worker) and try to run `wrangler dev` (which will run `npm run build`, which in turn runs `worktop build index.js`) I get the error message `sh: worktop: command not found`.

I have double checked that I have followed each step correctly, checked if `worktop` was present in the `node_modules` directory (it is) and also tried to install `worktop` globally (didn't work).

What am I missing here?

Full output of running `wrangler dev`:

```
$ wrangler dev     
  Running npm run build

> fauna-demo-workers@1.0.0 build /Users/me/dev/fauna-demo-workers
> worktop build index.js

sh: worktop: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! fauna-demo-workers@1.0.0 build: `worktop build index.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fauna-demo-workers@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2022-01-09T12_54_24_718Z-debug.log
Error: Build failed! Status Code: 1
```

Comment: `tried to install worktop globally (didn't work).` Were there any errors? There shouldn't be any problem installing it globally

Comment: No, it installed fine, but the error stayed the same. Also I running `worktop` from the command line (wherever, since it should be available globally) gave the same error `worktop: command not found`.

Answer (score 2):

you have to install the `worktop.build` package. That's where the `worktop` binary comes from. The package called “worktop” is just a runtime library. Not everyone will want to use its opinionated CLI/builder, hence the separate package.

(I'm the author of worktop & worktop.build)

Comment: Thanks! When installing `worktop.build` package I can no indeed use the `worktop` command. Still no luck running `worktop build index.js` as in the Faunadb tutorial, but maybe that's the tutorial's fault.

Comment: The `worktop build index.js` isn't meant to be run directly. You run it by running `wrangler dev`, which in turn invokes `npm run build` as you note.

I don't think the tutorial instructs you to run `worktop build index.js` anywhere; please correct me if I'm wrong.

(I'm a maintainer of the tutorial).

Comment: Correct. The tutorial sets up a `"build"` npm script (inside the `package.json` file), which is linked via the `wrangler.toml` file's configuration. Its `build.command` is assigned to `npm run build`, which Wrangler will run during development and as part of `wrangler publish`.